# I'm a complete noob and I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, sudo

How to add all repositories to have all software packages available for Ubuntu - like restricted, universe and multiverse and ppa via terminal commands?

Comment: They are already added if you did not remove them.

Comment: You would also need to determine the right country/region, to match existing entries in **`/etc/apt/sources.list`**.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check the connected repositories is in

System Settings -> Software & Updates

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your /etc/apt/sources.list file it should look something like this. (Note your mirror will differ depending where you are in the world. (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors))

billy@MYBOX:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
deb http://mirrors.us.kernel.org/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

To add ppa's:
billy@MYBOX:/etc/apt$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:someppa/ppa

then update repros:
billy@MYBOX:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update